# Socket connection in Next.js and Flutter

Tags: flutter, next.js, socket.io

I can't find a way to connect socket connection between next.js and Flutter.
Socket setup on next.js is alittle bit different to node.js/express. (socket server based on a route than port)(maybe I do not know how to build on port yet)

Tried: using muliple versions for server and clients( flutter x next.js).

Server itself is working, tested on next.js client to server.

So, how can we connect it? It'll be much appreciated if provides a link to research and learn. ( I already tried using different keywords and cant find one).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: sorry it somehow worked.

`IO.Socket socket = IO.io(('http://###.##.##.###:3000'), <String, dynamic>{
        'transports': ['websocket'],
        'autoConnect': false,
      });`
 didn't realized server address used was localhost and changed to ip address.